# Не устанавливается python 3.8.7

Tags: python, windows, установка

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]*Мне нужен пайтон 3.6x+ для F-строк вот лог, пайтон у меня не устанавливается:*[image: мои комплектующие]

```
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i001: Burn v3.11.1.2318, Windows v6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1), path: C:\Users\7349~1\AppData\Local\Temp\{8C5D82D6-0F97-427F-B8E8-DD8F4A551560}\.cr\python-3.8.7.exe
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'ShortVersion' to value '3.8'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'ShortVersionNoDot' to value '38'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVer' to value '3.8-32'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'WinVerNoDot' to value '38-32'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallAllUsers' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsers' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDir' to value ''
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultAllUsersTargetDir' to value '[ProgramFilesFolder]Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetPlatform' to value 'x86'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultJustForMeTargetDir' to value '[LocalAppDataFolder]Programs\Python\Python[WinVerNoDot]'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'OptionalFeaturesRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstalledFeatures'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirRegistryKey' to value 'Software\Python\PythonCore\[WinVer]\InstallPath'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'DefaultCustomTargetDir' to value ''
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'InstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value 'enabled'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomInstallLauncherAllUsersState' to value '[InstallLauncherAllUsersState]'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'TargetDirState' to value 'enabled'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'CustomBrowseButtonState' to value 'enabled'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_core' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_exe' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_dev' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_lib' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_test' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_doc' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tools' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_tcltk' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_pip' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_launcher' to value '-1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'Include_launcherState' to value 'enabled'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_symbols' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Include_debug' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'LauncherOnly' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedLauncher' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'DetectedOldLauncher' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'AssociateFiles' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'Shortcuts' to value '1'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'PrependPath' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'CompileAll' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing numeric variable 'SimpleInstall' to value '0'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Initializing string variable 'SimpleInstallDescription' to value ''
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i009: Command Line: '-burn.clean.room=C:\Users\пк\Downloads\python-3.8.7.exe -burn.filehandle.attached=148 -burn.filehandle.self=156'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSource' to value 'C:\Users\пк\Downloads\python-3.8.7.exe'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleOriginalSourceFolder' to value 'C:\Users\пк\Downloads\'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleLog' to value 'C:\Users\7349~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Python 3.8.7 (32-bit)_20221203194732.log'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleName' to value 'Python 3.8.7 (32-bit)'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Setting string variable 'WixBundleManufacturer' to value 'Python Software Foundation'
[08A0:089C][2022-12-03T19:47:32]i000: Setting numeric variable 'CRTInstalled' to value 1
[08A0:0844][2022-12-03T19:47:33]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstalling' to value 'Installing'
[08A0:0844][2022-12-03T19:47:33]i000: Setting string variable 'ActionLikeInstallation' to value 'Setup'
[08A0:0844][2022-12-03T19:47:33]i000: Setting version variable 'WixBundleFileVersion' to value '3.8.7150.0'
[08A0:0844][2022-12-03T19:47:33]e000: Detected Windows 7 SP1 without KB2533623
[08A0:0844][2022-12-03T19:47:33]e000: KB2533623 update is required to continue.
[![вот фото][1]][1]
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: 32x система у меня

Comment: я думал что уже нельзя на 7ке эту версию ,но нет. Note that Python 3.8.7 cannot be used on Windows XP or earlier.

Comment: а как установить не совсем догоняю? я с оффициального сайта скачивал

Comment: KB2533623 update is required to continue

Comment: MBo обновить что?

Comment: обновление винды KB2533623

Comment: Ну да, там какое-то обновление безопасности https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-security-advisory-insecure-library-loading-could-allow-remote-code-execution-486ea436-2d47-27e5-6cb9-26ab7230c704

Comment: Спасибо MBo у меня всё работает всего-то и надо было установить обновление KB2533623 для виндовс 7 Огромное спасибо